# Ranking showing 3 people

Tags: python, list, printing

Hey so the problem I am facing right now is that I would like to print the 3 highest grades but it is just showing error. I know its an easy problem but unfortunately I cannot solve it. Hope that somebody can show me my mistake and thanks in advance.

```
topperformer =  [19, 13, 17, 18, 18, 16, 15, 14, 16, 15]'
topperformer.sort
topperformer.reverse
print('The topperformer are',topperformer(:3)
```

Comment: There is an extra quote at the end of line 1

Answer (score 1):

```
topperformer =  [19, 13, 17, 18, 18, 16, 15, 14, 16, 15]

# Remove duplicates
topperformer = list(set(topperformer))

topperformer.sort()
topperformer.reverse()
print('The topperformer are', topperformer[0:3])
```

Comment: But if I do it as a set, so numbers don't repeat how would I print that one?          list.tops = set(topperformer)